# Reactjs location.search not working in react router v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
**const redirect = location.search? location.search.split('=') : "/account" ;
 useEffect(() => {
    if (error) {
      alert.error(error);
      dispatch(clearErrors());
    }
    if (isAuthenticated) {
      navigate(redirect);
    }
  }, [dispatch, error, alert, history, isAuthenticated, redirect]);**
```

this is not working anyone please tell me what i replace in this place so that my this function working.i am very grateful to you.

Comment: Are you using `const location = useLocation()` like this ?

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what the issue is other than "it's not working"? Please update your question to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

location.search will not give you the path of the URL, only the query params if exists in the URL. You have to use

```
   const location = useLocation();
   //For full URL, you have to use location.pathname + location.search
   //For just the path name :- location.pathname
   const redirect = location.pathname + location.search
```

Answer (score 0):

const redirect = [...searchParam][0] ? `/${[...searchParam][0][1]}` : '/account';

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In new version of RRD v6, location is replaced with useLocation. Try the following Code.
Step 1: Import useLocation

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
```

Step 2:

```
const location = useLocation()
```

Step 3:

```
const redirect = location.search ? location.search.split("=")[1] : "/account"
```

Step 4: Add redirect in useEffect

```
[dispatch, error, alert, navigate, isAuthenticated, redirect]
```